# WKWebView in UITableViewCustomCell not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, wkwebview

I wanted to show a web page in a custom cell and wrote codes as follows, but I could not get it work.

The app crashes at "self.webView!.navigationDelegate = self" line saying "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0".

If I comment out this line, I can build it, but the app shows nothing. (The height of this cell becomes zero and I see no content.)

I would appreciate advice.

ContentViewController.swift(view controller with a UITableView)

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
  var cell : ArticleWKWebViewCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ArticleWKWebViewCustomCell") as! ArticleWKWebViewCustomCell

            return cell
        }
else ....(abbreviated)
```

ArticleWKWebViewCustomCell.swift
    import UIKit
    import WebKit

```
class ArticleWKWebViewCustomCell: UITableViewCell, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

         self.webView!.navigationDelegate = self

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        view.addSubview(self.webView!)

        let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.yahoo.co.jp")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        println("Finished navigating to url")
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, thanks to advice from a friend of mine.
I turned out that I needed to set the size of the frame for webView.
I added below code after `view.addSubview(self.webView!)`

```
self.webView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(view.frame))
```